# Not getting output parameter with visual studio generated dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something silly here.
I am inserting a record into a database table and my stored procedure uses an output parameter. My insert works but I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

My c#  business logic code is below:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
public int CreatePage(int? parentPage, string pageTitle, string pageDescript, string pageCont, int basePage, ref int? insertedrecord)
{

    int finaloutput = 0;
    string errormess;

    if(basePage > 0)
    {

        if(pageTitle != String.Empty)
        {
            if(pageDescript != String.Empty)
            {
                if(pageCont != String.Empty)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(parentPage == 0)
                        {
                            parentPage = null;
                        }

                        finaloutput = (int)pgAdp.InsertNewPage(parentPage, pageTitle, pageDescript, pageCont, basePage, ref insertedrecord);
                    }
                    catch(Exception er)
                    {
                        errormess = er.Message;

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

    return finaloutput; 

}
```

and my code behind:

```
 string pgtitle = txtPageTitle.Text;
    string pgdescript = txtDescript.Text;
    int parpg;
    int basepg;
    int? outputtedident = 0;
    int.TryParse(drpParentPages.SelectedValue, out parpg);
    int.TryParse(drpBasePagesList.SelectedValue, out basepg);
    string pgcont = txtContent.Text;
    int newpageid = pagesLogic.CreatePage(parpg, pgtitle, pgdescript, pgcont, basepg, ref outputtedident);
```

Any ideas what's going on?

EDIT:
As some helpful soul took it upon themselves to down vote and vote to close the question I thought I'd add further clarification.

The dataset was generated by visual studio from stored procedures. The insert works, so I get my new record in the database, but I need the value of the output parameter, which in the business logic code below is 'insertedrecord'

```
finaloutput = (int)pgAdp.InsertNewPage(parentPage, pageTitle, pageDescript, pageCont, basePage, ref insertedrecord);
```

I need the value of 'insertedrecord' as part of a url to redirect the user to another page.

My sql stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SitePages].[InsertNewPage] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ParentPageId int,
@PageTitle varchar(100),
@PageDescription nvarchar(250),
@PageCont nvarchar(max),
@BasePage int,
@InsertedIdent int output

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO SitePages.Pages(ParentPageId, PageTitle, PageDescription, PageContent, Published, BasePageId)
VALUES (@ParentPageId, @PageTitle, @PageDescription, @PageCont, 0, @BasePage)

set @InsertedIdent = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
return @InsertedIdent
END
```

Like I said the insert is going off without a hitch but I am getting an exception as I mentioned at the beginning but I don't really know why.

The exception occurs on this line:

```
finaloutput = (int)pgAdp.InsertNewPage(parentPage, pageTitle, pageDescript, pageCont, basePage, ref insertedrecord);
```

Comment: On what line do you get this exception?

Comment: I've updated the question @Cal279

Comment: But to answer directly I get it on the following line: finaloutput = (int)pgAdp.InsertNewPage(parentPage, pageTitle, pageDescript, pageCont, basePage, ref insertedrecord);

Comment: In that case your pgAdp object must be null. How are you initializing it?

Comment: I have managed to sort it. I was trying to return the function rather than just the output parameter. I have added return Convert.ToInt32(insertedrecord); after the insert in the business logic and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for your assistance any way, it is greatly appreciated